# Bazel run action via .bat file shows warning and shuts down

Tags: batch-file, cmd, bazel

I run my bazel C++ project successfully with custom argument using the following command in powershell/cmd

```
start bazel run -c opt main -- --players="5"
```

but when I try to run the same command using a custom .bat file

```
echo off
start cmd /k CD C:\Users\user\Documents\Code\game
start bazel run -c opt main -- --players="5"
```

new cmd window pops up with the error/warning is as follows before this cmd window shuts down

> G: Invoking Bazel in batch mode since it is not invoked from within a
> workspace (below a directory having a WORKSPACE file). OpenJDK 64-Bit
> Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated
> in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.

**EDIT:** Thanks to **user: compo**, I was able to build the program using the .bat file but cmd window doesn't seem to stay open for far too long. Following are the changes I've tried so far. None of them seem to keep the window open for longer than program finishes building and briefly launching before the cmd window abruptly closing right after.

```
@START /REALTIME /WAIT /B /D "%UserProfile%\Documents\Code\game" bazel run -c opt main -- --players="5"

@CD /D "%UserProfile%\Documents\Code\game" 2>NUL && bazel run -c opt main -- --players="5"
```

Comment: If you open a Command Prompt window, type `start /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key, it explains to you how the command is used. Just a one line batch file example: ```@START /D "%UserProfile%\Documents\Code\game" bazel run -c opt main -- --players="5"```.

Comment: Thanks, @Compo that actually worked. However after the command gets executed and runs for a second or two, cmd abruptly closes. Why would that be? using pause doesn't let the command run and pauses everything. Is there something else I could try? thanks.

Comment: Maybe, for your purposes, you want to use an additional one of the other options from the output I've already shown you how to produce! `@START /D "%UserProfile%\Documents\Code\game" /WAIT bazel run -c opt main -- --players="5"`. Alternatively forget about using `START`, `@CD /D "%UserProfile%\Documents\Code\game" 2>NUL && bazel run -c opt main -- --players="5"`.

Comment: @Compo I've edited my answer. I'm able to build and run my program successfully but the cmd window abruptly closing issue unfortunately persists even after using the /WAIT param. Please let me know if you think I could try something else.

Comment: Did you play with `Start`'s `/B` option? and what was wrong with the option I gave without `start`?

Comment: I did, @Compo. I've already answered the question. Apparently it required 2 options, /B and /p. Please have a look at my answer to the question. That works without abruptly shutting down the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set /p=
worked for me, to be used at the end of the command. It will expect user input and will release the flow when enter is pressed. In my case:

```
@START /B /D "%UserProfile%\Documents\Code\game" bazel run -c opt main -- --players="5"

set /p=
```

Comment: `Set` with its `/P` option is simply a second command, and should have no bearing on your task. The only thing it is doing is preventing the script from progressing whilst it awaits input. I don't see why it is needed here over a `pause` or even `timeout`.

Comment: neither pause, nor /k seem to stop the cmd window from shutting down after program has finished building and executing however @Compo but set /p= does. Would you know why that is?

Comment: For `set /p=` to run, the previous command must have completed. In such a scenario, the command you choose just to prevent the script from immediately ending, and potentially closing the `cmd.exe`window, should not matter. `Set /P "="`,  or `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /K`, in their more correct form, should not act differently to `Pause` or `%SystemRoot%\System32\ timeout.exe /T -1`, in that regard.